# Download file by form PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to dowloand json data by form PHP.
File is downloading but dsnt get name which one i defined, also in file print only two characters from my json data.

File inside looks like:

> [{

When json data looks:

> [{"SIZE":[16,16]}]

He is code:

```
var dataAsText = JSON.stringify(data); 
var filename=$("#menu-save-text").val();
var _content = dataAsText;
jQuery('<form action="download.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'+filename +'" /><input type="hidden" name="content" value="'+_content+'" /></form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

PHP:

```
<?
            $filename=$POST["filename"];
            header("Content-type: text/plain"); 
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.""); 
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Cache-Control: private",false);

            echo $_POST["content"];        
    ?>
```

Downloaded files name is download.php

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: Why build a form to do your post at all rather than use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()`?

Comment: Coz I Don't know what to put into `success:function() {}`. I just start learning php today :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suffering from an HTML injection vulnerability. The `"` in the JSON is breaking your HTML:

e.g. the html you build looks like this:

```
[..snip..]<input type="hidden" name="content" value="[{"SIZE":[16,16]}]" />[..snip..]
```

Which will be parsed by the browser as:

```
input:
  value="[}"         // proper attribute
  size":[16,etc...  // unknown/illegal html attribute
```

In other words, you need to quote your JSON for usage in an html form attribute, e.g. change all the `"` to `&quot;`. That or build the HTML using proper dom methods, and set the content input's value via `$(...).val(json_goes_here)`-type operations with jquery.

Comment: OK i will try it. But what about filename?

Comment: same thing. doesn't matter WHAT you're putting into the html, it HAS to conform to html syntax requirements. if you're building the html yourself, then it's up to you to make sure it's syntactically correct.

Comment: But variable `filename` doesnt has `"`.

Comment: yeah, but you've using `$POST['filename']`. Notice the missing `_`. You really need to turn on the debug output options in PHP, especially while developing. You'd have been told about the undefined index in an undefined array. e.g. enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your php.ini